# When parsing text how do i advance the startPos index each time to keep searching?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private List<string> ExtractFromString(string s, string startTag, string endTag)
        {
            var names = new List<string>();
            int startPos = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                startPos = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(textBox2.Text) + textBox2.Text.Length;
                if (startPos == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                int endPos = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(textBox3.Text, startPos);
                string extractedText = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos).Trim();

            }
            return names;
        }
```

For example in richTextBox1 i have some text and in textBox2.Text i have dan and in textbox3.Text i have lip and in the middle iel.

Now i want to loop over the text in richTextBox1 and from index 0 to seach for all the places that start with dan and end with lip and extract the text between in all the places.

Not sure if the loop is the right way useing true ?
And i need also somehow to advance the startPos after doing the subString so it will keep continue searching in the next indexs.

Later i will change to use startTag and endTag now i'm using textBox2.Text and textBox3.Text as tags it dosen't matter now. Just the idea how do i make the search for the tags in all places from index 0 and extract the text between this tags in all places the tags found except the first place.

For example if textBox2.Text is dan and textBox3.Text lip and i know this strings exist in the text i selected them so in any case this tags exist at least once since i'm selecting them each time.

Now search in all other places on the text to see if this tags exist somewhere else again and extract the text in this places too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has 3 major problems:

First, `startPos` will never be -1, since it's already being added the length of `textBox2.Text`.
You should first test if it's -1, and only if it's not then add the length.
Second, you need to specify what is the first position to start looking for the index of the `textBox2.Text`. Do that by using a different overload of the `IndexOf` method (the same that you use for the `endPos`, actually):

```
startPos = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(textBox2.Text, endPos);
if (startPos == -1)
{
    break;
}
startPos += textBox2.Text.Length;
```

The third problem is that you never add the names to the List.
It should be added once found:

```
string extractedText = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos).Trim();
if(!string.isNullOrEmpty(extractedText)
{
    names.Add(extractedText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a second parameter to `IndexOf`, as you do when searching the end tag. For each next iteration specify the previous `endPos` as the starting position of the new search. Initialize `endPos` to 0 to make it work on the first iteration.

```
private List<string> ExtractFromString(string s, string startTag, string endTag)
    {
        var names = new List<string>();
        int startPos = 0;
        int endPos = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            startPos = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(textBox2.Text, endpos) + textBox2.Text.Length;
            if (startPos == -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            int endPos = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(textBox3.Text, startPos);
            string extractedText = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos).Trim();

        }
        return names;
    }
```